# How to run parameterized jUnit tests with a custom delimiter/separator

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, junit4

I want to run unit test on file in this format:

```
Target; targeT; true

Targe1; targe2; true
```

I saw these two open source projects:

[junitparams](https://github.com/Pragmatists/junitparams) - cannot set a non CSV-file as an input

[zohhak](https://code.google.com/p/zohhak/wiki/FullGuide#DRYing_configuration) - can customize the separator but not set a file as an input

I have tried to implement my own file reader but it fails sometimes and also assert "false" on one line crashes the whole test (in contrast to `junitparams` framework).

How can I insert a **non-CSV-file** as batch input (with a delimiter different than `,`)

Comment: Please don't post two questions for the same / similar issue. Update the first post if additional details become relevant. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105630/can-i-change-somehow-the-delimiter-in-junitparameterized

Comment: Can you share your problematic code here? Looks to me that you have a minor issue...

Comment: i will, but assertion not as expected usually crashes the UT. so it's not related to my code.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use | as a separator.

Also you may investigate [this code](https://code.google.com/p/junitparams/source/browse/src/main/java/junitparams/internal/InvokeParameterisedMethod.java?name=JUnitParams-1.0.2) and have a look at 
private static Pattern splitPattern